# which npm package is used? package under project or home directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there any tool or command to print out npm package local path? Similar to the 'which' command in linux. I run into a problem where an npm package was missing from my project's package.json undetected until it was deployed. Locally the project run as it used the package from my home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`require.resolve('module')`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_resolve), instead of `require('module')`, to get the path to the module instead of loading the module itself.